# Using Google Sheets API without a cloud platform project

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I need to save some data to private Google Sheets as part of my pet project. I have reviewed the documentation and I am a bit confused about having to create a cloud platform project for such small task. Is there any way to use Google Sheets API(or write data to Google Sheets without it somehow) and don't use google cloud platform?

Comment: What's is cloud platform project? Can you share the link of reading which suggest that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To consume Sheets API, you must identify the caller using Oauth 2.0 and in the end a Google Cloud Platform project is needed. [More information here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing)
- Quoting: `When your application requests public data, the request doesn't need to be authorized, but does need to be accompanied by an identifier, such as an API key.`, so even if you are fetching data from a publicly available Sheets you still need to identify the caller.
- To register and generate credentials (OAuth / API key) a Google Cloud Platform project is needed